# Fancybox - Modify javascript to add options

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have the following Fancybox declarations in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox().hover(function() {
            $(this).click();
        });
        $("#fancybox-outer").fancybox().mouseleave( function() {
               $("#fancybox-overlay").click();
         });
    });
</script>
```

I need to reduce the size of the image used by the modal box and I believe I can do that by setting the "autoDimensions", "width", and "height" options available with Fancybox, I just don't know how to integrate that with the hover function, since there isn't an option in Fancybox to specify a function for a hover event. (I hope this is making sense.)

Anyhow, does anyone know how I can modify the above javascript to control the width and height?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but `images` in fancybox don't use "`autoDimensions`", "`width`", and "`height`" API options. Those options are for `ajax`, `iframe` or `inline` content only.

Images in fancybox are displayed either, re-sized to fit into the viewport (when `autoScale` is set to `true`) or in their original size (when `autoScale` is set to `false`). If the original size is bigger than the height of the viewport, then you have to scroll down the parent page to see the whole image.

The only way you can re-size images in fancybox other than above is using `jQuery css()` API (which, I wouldn't advise ... it produces an odd behavior). You can call it using fancybox's callback option `onComplete` like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
   'onComplete': function(){
    $("#fancybox-outer, #fancybox-content").css({'width':300,'height':150});
   }
  }).hover(function() {
   $(this).click();
  });
  $("#fancybox-outer").fancybox().mouseleave( function() {
   $("#fancybox-overlay").click();
  });
 });
</script>
```

**Note** that options mentioned above are for fancybox v1.3.x.

Use it at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

you can always add code to document.ready to trigger every time. so just check for the event and resize.

or since the elements are hidden at first, you can get the event trigger using the show event

Answer (score 0):

Check for the event onstart. onstart will be called right before attempting to load the content, and you can add your resize operations there.